# Bash if statement with regex

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

I try to use REGEX in bash in order to check if the parameter seems to be a valid path following this format:

```
/first/second
```

In java I use with success the following REGEX :

```
((\\/)[a-zA-Z0-9\\s_@\\-!#$%&+=]+)+
```

But in bash I have some issue that I can't explain.
In order to simplify my comprehension I try to use a simpler REGEX like that:

```
CHECKPATH="!/first/second"
REGEX_PATH="((\/)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+"
if [[ ! ${CHECKPATH} =~ $REGEX_PATH ]]; then
    echo "error"
else
    echo "OK"
fi
```

I insert an "!" in the path just to check. So I should have "error" but not. With or without the "!" it changes nothing, what's the problem?

**Update:** (moved author's subquestion here from a comment)

One more thing, if I use `^((\/)[a-zA-Z0-9\s_@#&%!$+=\-]+)+$` it's ok, but it's not with `^((\/)[a-zA-Z0-9\s_@\-#&%!$+=]+)+$`. I just changed the position of "\-" inside the regex, why?

Comment: you might need to add ^ and $ for begins with and ends with. try testing it here: http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: Works for me in `bash` 3.2 and and 4.3, with or with the `!` in the value of `CHECKPATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some regex libraries (possible the Java one you use) have methods that specifically test the regex against the whole input string.

But in bash (and generally in regex) you use:

- `^` - match start of the input, and
- `$` - match end of the input

So instead try,

```
REGEX_PATH="^((\/)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$"
```

**Update:**

You have to put the dash on the start/end.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html :

> To include a literal '-', make it the first or last character, or the second endpoint of a range.  To use a literal '-' as the first endpoint of a range, enclose it in "[." and ".]"  to make it a collating element (see below).

AND (same link) [emphasis mine]

> With the exception of these and some combinations using '[' (see next paragraphs), all other special characters, **including '\', lose their special significance** within a bracket expression.

Comment: One more thing, if I use ^((\/)[a-zA-Z0-9\s_@#&%!$+=\-]+)+$ it's ok, but it's not with ^((\/)[a-zA-Z0-9\s_@\-#&%!$+=]+)+$. I just change the position of "\-" inside the regex, why ?

Comment: @gduh I've moved this subquestion to the original question and added update to my answer.